# iPad : Crash because of add more than three CCSpriteFrameCache file

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

In my cocos2d application I have used Five CCSpriteFrameCache(.plist) file. when I load more than three .plist file app getting crash.

just it printing like that

```
2012-06-08 16:45:08.575 VoiceChangingBowtie[5611:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'windowAnimationsiPad.png' as texture

2012-06-08 16:45:13.089 VoiceChangingBowtie[5611:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'iPadShark.png' as texture

2012-06-08 16:45:14.297 VoiceChangingBowtie[5611:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'iPadSharkSecond.png' as texture ...
```

then app crashed

Comment: ..and, what's your crash message? You give us no context to help you with.

Comment: @skram I didn't get any error message , just it printing like that 2012-06-08 16:45:08.575 VoiceChangingBowtie[5611:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'windowAnimationsiPad.png' as texture
2012-06-08 16:45:13.089 VoiceChangingBowtie[5611:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'iPadShark.png' as texture
2012-06-08 16:45:14.297 VoiceChangingBowtie[5611:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'iPadSharkSecond.png' as texture .............. then app crashed.

Comment: Please show use the piece of code where you are loading your textures.

Comment: @skram this is my code- [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"windowAnimations%@.plist",                                                                            deviceType]];[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iPadDog.plist"]]; [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iPadDogSecond.plist"]];               [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iPadCat.plist"]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crash with no message almost in all cases mean that you have troubles with memory. How big are your textures that you are trying to load? Check memory usage with instruments tool.

Comment: my texture size is 4096*4096, and also i have tried 2048*2048 size it also crashed when load more than five texture. Then i have tried instrument tool there also app crash without error message

Comment: each 2048x2048 texture eats about 16Mb of memory. Even 5 such textures will cause memory warnings. I don't think that it is possible to use more textures without crashes on all retina devices. At least you will have troubles with retina iPods and the first iPads